# How to scale websocket service?

Tags: websocket, architecture, broadcast

I have websocket service that broadcast some data to the app. It get it by the Redis Keyspace Notifications, each key looks like prefix-userUuid : payload. It check uuid in opened connections and sends data, it works ok. But now I want to scale it and get the problem, since if I increase amount of services all of them will receive all data and then look though connected users. What would be better architecture for scaling this service?

Comment: The specific details matter.  It isn't clear from your question what exactly you need to scale and why, and therefore it isn't possible to usefully answer your question.

Comment: This is a service in microservice app, I need to run multiple instances of it for high availability etc. There is map with connections and sockets. Data comes to the service and it broadcast it to appropriate connection based on uuid. The other service sends data with format uuid:payload. The problem is that  if we scale broadcast service to 10, we still need to send each message to all of them since we don't know which one has connection from particular uuid(user).

Comment: It still isn't clear at all what the problem is.  What does your service actually do?  You're just trying to send data form one place to another?  You're trying to send the same data to everyone?  What, **specifically**?  If this is just a pub/sub with most messages from one to the next, you can maintain a central registry of what's connected where.  A lot of what you do depends on how you're partitioning the load anyway.

Comment: It is websocket service, that connect backend with browser app. So it sends data from backend to frontend though websockets.

Comment: What data?  How often?  Are the messages sent 1:1?  1:many?  What's the origin of the messages?  What are the latency requirements?  How have you partitioned the load across all these instances?  Is there any reliability requirement, or should it be best-effort?  Do you need to store/retrieve the messages later?

Comment: Data is json, sent 1:1. Origin is another service publishing it in redis. I don't need to store\retrieve the message. Sorry can't answer another questions. This is pretty much, what I was looking for https://hackernoon.com/scaling-websockets-9a31497af051

Comment: If you're already using Redis, why not use Redis to back any number of Web Socket services?  It's already quite performant.

Comment: You just don't understand the problem.

Comment: @ogbofjnr Did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @SudhanshuGarg at a time I didn't implement the solution. But looks like the only way is to create dedicated topic/queue in message broker on user's WS connection . Usually there is no limit on number of queues, so it will work. 

Another idea is to use hash function on user id.

Comment: @ogbofjnr I am doing it by using a dictionary storing socket.id for each connected userid